# ListView Item appear strange drawable

Tags: android, listview, animation, progress-bar, drawable

I have a poblem when custom progress bar. I create a animaiton drawable  for progressbar. After I set this drawable for progressbar when dialog loading data show.

File anim_loading.xml

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/icon_loading"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" />
```

After I set this drawable for dialog loading data.

```
public void showProgressDialog(String content, boolean cancleable) {
    progressDlg = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", content, true, true);
    progressDlg.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anim_loading));
    progressDlg.setCancelable(cancleable);
    progressDlg.setOnCancelListener(this);
}
```

But in android 2.2x or 2.3x Listview appear drawable icon_loading in row of data. I can't undestand .. :(

I attached two file (image). Correctly with android 4.0, and error with android 2.3 or 2.2
[image]

[image]

Layout row :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_item_selector"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/RED_COLOR"
        android:textSize="25.0sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtCode"
        android:padding="1.0dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/BLACK_COLOR"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFavorite"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_love_small" /> 
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDetail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/llContent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/BLACK_COLOR"
            android:textSize="12.0sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Selector of row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/SEA_BLUE" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/SEA_BLUE" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/TRANSPARENT"/>

</selector>
```

Hope somebody help me find this bug.
Thanks so much!

p/s Sorry I hide content data in listview :)

Comment: post the xml layout of the row.

Comment: Everybody can understand this problem, help me :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a starnge problem. I just solved it but I can't explain the reason.
The point is at:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/TRANSPARENT"/>
```

You should not set the normal background of listview item to be transparent  with android 2.3 or 2.2. Change the color and you will get correct result.